# How to add an Azure function accessible by everyone (even by non authenticated user) into an AAD secured Azure Function App

Tags: azure-functions

I have an AAD secured Azure Function App containing 4 azure functions.
As a result, all of them require an AAD authentication to be consumed.
I would like to add one more azure function to my Azure function App that can be consumed even by non authenticated users.
Is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, if your function app secured by AAD, you cannot add a function that can be consumed by non authenticated users. This is stated in the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization#allow-only-authenticated-requests)

> Restricting access in this way applies to all calls to your app, which may not be desirable for apps wanting a publicly available home page, as in many single-page applications.

[image]

If possible, I suggest you create another Function App to create functions that do not require AAD authentication.